# How to discover live hosts on same network using C kernel module?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ping

I'm writing a kernel module to send a special packet to every live host on the same network as the host running the module. I'm not totally sure how to discover live hosts on same network using C kernel code. I've looked into ping.c code and think its too much just for discovery of live hosts.

I could use application level utility like nmap to ping and get the data back to kernel module, but it would defeat the purpose of my module. Any ideas are welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Defeat the purpose of your module? What *is* the purpose of your module?

Comment: It could be that an ARP approach is appropriate (i.e something that works like the 'arping' tool). Further information in your question would help with understanding what the requirements are. Is your special packet TCP, UDP or other?